# Не работает данный js на айфоне

Tags: javascript

```
$(function () {
    var mixer = mixitup('.directions__list');
    $('.directions__filter-btn').on('click', function () {
        $('.directions__filter-btn').removeClass('directions__filter-btn--active')
        $(this).addClass('directions__filter-btn--active')
    })
})
```

Comment: https://github.com/vasyldubno/project1 https://vasyldubno.github.io/project1/index.html

Comment: А какой браузер у вас? И какая его версия? Включён ли JS в вашем браузере? Какую версию jQuery вы используете? Какая версия **mixitup** у вас? На данные вопросы ответы должны быть прямо **в вопросе**, вопрос можно изменить нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1422852/edit), в следующий раз постарайтесь уточнять детали, иначе скорее всего вам не ответят.

Comment: браузер google chrome (последняяя версия). js включен. jquery 3.6.0. mixitup3

Answer (score 3):

### Варианта 1: Использование `touchstart`

```
$(function () {
  var isIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
  var eventClick = 'click';
  if(isIOS) eventClick = 'touchstart';
  var mixer = mixitup('.directions__list');
  $('.directions__filter-btn').on(eventClick, function () {
    $('.directions__filter-btn').removeClass('directions__filter-btn--active')
    $(this).addClass('directions__filter-btn--active')
  })
})
```

Говорят, из-за данного решения может не работать скролл. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

### Вариант 2: Добавить к элементу пустой `onclick` атрибут

Чтобы ваш код заработал, нужно добавить `onclick=""` к элементу по которому идёт клик.

В вашем случае получается так

```
<div class="directions__filter-btn" onclick="">...</div>
```

### Вариант 3: `cursor: pointer`

Не знаю зачем, но IPhone надо, чтобы элемент по которому можно кликнуть имел `cursor: pointer`.
Я сталкивался с этим когда не работал `:hover`, но оказывается это ещё и решает проблему с `.onclick`

```
.directions__filter-btn {cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: А `.on('click touchstart'` не приведёт к двум вызовам функции вместо одного? Т. е. по одному на каждое событие? Ну или preventDefault может надо влепить чтобы после touchstart не происходил click?

Comment: Хм, точно, думаю лучше вообще убрать этот вариант.